# Prove that $\cos(x)=x$ for some $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus

I wish to prove that $\cos(x)=x$ for some unique $x \in [0,1]$. I know that I could use the intermediate value theorem here, but now quite sure how to use this. We know that $\cos(0)=1$ and that $\cos(x)$ is a continuous function on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ponder $\cos(x) - x$.

Comment: Notice that $cos(0)-0=1$ and $cos(1)-1<0$ so by the intermediate value theorem there must exist at least one values  for which $cos(x) -x =0 \rightarrow cos(x)=x $.

Comment: There is no uniqueness. Where did that come from? Draw a picture.

Comment: There exists **at least one value** for which [...]. That's what @copper.hat is referring to

Comment: $cos(x)$  and $-x$ are strictly decreasing on the interval $[0,1]$, therefore there is one unique value $x$ for which $cos(x)-x=0$.

Comment: Just to clarify my comment, the IVT gives existence not uniqueness. To conclude uniqueness you need more analysis.

Comment: Does my noticing monotonicity prove it though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\cos x-x$. Then $f(0)=1>0$ and $f(1)= \cos 1-1<0$. The intermediate value theorem gives some $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

It is your turn to show that $f$ is strictly monotonic on $ [0,1]$ .

Conclusion ?

Comment: $\cos(x)$  is strictly decreasing on the interval $[0,1]$ and so is $-x$. The sum is therefore monotonically decreasing so there must exist one unique value.

Comment: *strictly decreasing, monotonicity does not imply uniqueness, as the constant function is monotonic.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\cos(x)-x$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, and you have $$f(0)=1 > 0$$ and $$f(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}- \frac{\pi}{4} < \frac{1,5}{2} - \frac{3}{4} = 0$$

Bu the mean value theorem, $f$ has a zero on $[0, \frac{\pi}{4}]$, so it has one on $[0,1]$.